# Ringtones ring only once for alarms and calls in Cyanogenmod 11

Tags: alarm, ringtone

I have the latest monthly Cyanogenmod 11 installed on my Samsung Galaxy SII phone. This past week, I noticed that the alarms I set (with both the built in alarm app and the I Can't Wake Up app from the Play Store) only ring once then goes silent (the alarm is still on the screen and the phone still vibrates). This is also true for incoming calls, the ringtone rings only once. I tried changing ringtones to no effect.

Looks like this is an issue that's not limited to a specific ringtone or app. How can I troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using built-in ringtones, or your own audio files like MP3s?

Comment: I am using ringtones installed via the Zedge app. I checked, the builtin ringtones ring fine and repeat, but not the ones from Zedge.

Answer (score 2):

In recent Android versions in order for a ringtone to repeat on a loop, MP3 and OGG files must include a label in their metadata called `android_loop` with a value set to "true".  If you are not using built-in ringtones (that already have this label,) your files most likely do not have this label in their metadata.

You can use a number of freeware utilities (such as [WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com/), for example) to edit the metadata of OGG files and set this flag, or [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) for MP3 files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I installed those ringtones via the Zedge app, and after checking they are indeed missing the android_loop tag set to "true". However, after adding the tag those ringtones still don't repeat! Is there anything else I can try? Thanks!